# When we Fetch Request, why do we use Like instead of ==?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",

        attributeName, attributeValue];
```

Why not

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",

        attributeName, attributeValue];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, you're just following the pattern that the creators made. They could have implemented it using `==`, but it would have made less sense. Generally, `==` means exactly equal to, as in references being equal. This is a pattern match, so you want to find items that are "like" a pattern, not necessarily equal to a pattern.

`NSPredicate`'s support using the `==` operator, but it performs differently than the `like` operator does:

```
NSPredicate *newPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:aBool]];
NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == YES"];
```

Comment: What's the difference between ==  and like

Comment: Oh I get it, == check that the reference is equal, which is stupid. Is LIKE match an inexact match?

Comment: For example will "Maria" like "Mary" returns true? That's what confused me

Comment: @Jim: No. "Maria" like "Mary" would not return true. It works like the SQL `LIKE` operator, and it's like a simpler version of RegEx. Say you had a list of Names that included `Peter`, `Paul`, and `Mary`. You could do `Name like P*`, which would return `Peter` ad `Paul` since they start with a "P", but not `Mary`.